# Python Script not POSTing image data to API

Tags: python, json, rest, post, python-requests

I'm trying to upload a picture to an API and am running into trouble.  It doesn't seem to be saving the file as an actual image onto the server.

The method works without any errors and gives me a `200` status code, however, when I inspect the link for the media file that is uploaded, it is a JSON file, rather than a link to an image.

**This is my function:**

```
def post_media():
   api_url = '{0}media'.format(api_url_base)
   json_content = {"type":"image","file" :( "profile_pic",open("profile.png","rb"))}
   response = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers, data=json_content)
  
   if response.status_code == 200:
      print("post media success")
```

It works "successfully", but when I inspect the media objects now on the server, the one I uploaded gives me [this link](https://cdn.eyo.net/production/raw/upload/v1557190953/uCslgzzqaJW7xODphBmIRVhcySEpVW7T5fwTZWTArGOLcIHSCagFBEUsmrdQqQniBF1Fm9houTl9nYMaM2NLHVM6p4EXhzdXrcLTPm1OlHvgfaLWn27ksO2YhbnntI88A8nP0QP4sFMLImOeUEisnXtbSPtOWmB4qD5sd6IoImHEEBA91RQvJ9a0oSXWPJcy/null.null).

which downloads a text file that contains only the following text:

```
type=image&file=profile_pic&file=%3C_io.BufferedReader+name%3D%27profile.png%27%3E
```

which is definitely not my image file.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong so that it uploads an actual image rather than just some text data.

---

## Solution

I figured it out just after posting this.  All I had to do was change the parameter from `data=json_content` to `files=json_content`. Woohoo! Thanks anyway :)